# R: Convert quote to string

Tags: r, string

Given a variable `foo` which is a quote

```
foo = quote(1+2)
class(foo)
# [1] "call"
```

I want to extract the string `"1+2"`. How?

PS: `as.character(foo)` just gives me the components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `deparse`

```
deparse(foo)
#[1] "1 + 2"
```